# Http Libraries Comparison fro Android. Which is Preferred?

Tags: android, httpconnection

What are some of the best alternatives for HTTP Connectivity Libraries to use in Android application, in terms of performance and also, multi-part uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tow library mostly used for perform network Related operations, which are followings,

1. [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

2. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

Check http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/
and 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries
.........................